# Create new column in pandas based on whether datetime values are within an hour

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

If I have a dataframe in pandas like:

```
StartDate,           EndDate,              uniqueid
2015-07-20 15:04:13, 2015-07-20 17:56:00,  1
2015-07-20 20:32:16, 2015-07-20 20:56:11,  3
2015-07-20 22:35:59, 2015-07-20 22:51:10,  11
2015-07-20 18:00:51, 2015-07-20 18:42:01,  12
```

I want to create a new column which has in indicator value if in the list there exists a StartDate less than an hour after the rows EndDate. So an example output would look like:

```
StartDate,           EndDate,              uniqueid, WithinHour
2015-07-20 15:04:13, 2015-07-20 17:56:00,  1,        1
2015-07-20 20:32:16, 2015-07-20 20:56:11,  3,        0   
2015-07-20 22:35:59, 2015-07-20 22:51:10,  11,       0
2015-07-20 18:00:51, 2015-07-20 18:42:01,  12,       0
```

Because row 1 has

```
EndDate 2015-07-20 17:56:00
```

and row 4 has

```
StartDate 2015-07-20 18:00:51
```

which is within 1 hour.

There should not be any overlap in start and end date for the rows, so I think I should order by startdate, create a new column with the (StartDate of the next row) - (EndDate of this row), then change the value of the new column to 1 if the time is less than an hour and 0 if it's greater. I'm not sure how to do this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way. For each `EndDate`, apply the datetime range test you want. Use `any` to get the scalar answer as your value will be True if at least one row matches:

```
df['uniqueid'] = df.EndDate.apply(lambda dt: (((df.StartDate-pd.Timedelta(1, 'h')) <= dt)
                                             & (df.StartDate >= dt )).any())

df.uniqueid
Out[57]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: uniqueid, dtype: bool
```